# PDO::execute() is an undefined method for me?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is the PDO code in question:

```
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (id, name, password, salt, email, join_date, chats)
              VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$db->execute(array($name, $password, $salt, $email, $joindate, ''));
```

I get the fatal error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in register.php on line 12`, line 12 being the execute above. What could be wrong? The array contains perfect strings, checked them with a print_r.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`PDO::prepare` returns a `PDOStatement` object which has the `execute` method.

```
$st = $db->prepare(...);
$st->execute(...);
```